# I have used the database mailing system to send the email. But i could not figure our whether the email is sent or not

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have used the database mailing system to send the email. But i could not figure our whether the email is sent or not.
Is there any system table in sql server 2008 to insert the log whether the mail is sent or not. I want the sent 'email date from' , 'email date to' and Email Sent to. And is there any field that stores the mail sent like 'yes' or 'no'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191278%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  There are several tables in the msdb (system database) that are useful for tracking outgoing email status.  From the article:

> The Database Mail external program logs activity and displays the log
>   through the Windows Application Event Log and the sysmail_event_log
>   view in the msdb database. To check the status of an e-mail message,
>   run a query against this view. E-mail messages have one of four
>   possible statuses: sent, unsent, retrying, and failed.

Further, you can track additional info about the failures if you set the logging level to verbose when you configured your server for database mail.